# Who is Elisha (الْيَسَعَ)?

Tags: prophets

Prophet Elisha (Arabic: الْيَسَعَ) is mentioned in a couple of ayaat of Qur'an. I can't recall ever reading about him or hearing anything about his biography.

Who is he? Do we have any details from the Qur'an and sunnah (and perhaps also israiliyaat)?

For example, he is mentioned in [Surah Al-An'aam verse 86](http://quran.com/6/86), and [Surah Saad, verse 48](http://quran.com/38/48) -- albeit without details.

Comment: Can you reefer ayahs please ?

Comment: Elisha? Correct me if I am wrong but I am sure there is no female prophet.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back you are correct, Elisha is a name of a Prophet (peace be upon him)

Answer (score 2):

الْيَسَعَ full name is (اليسع بن أخْطُوب بن العجوز) Al Yasa' bin Ukhtoob bin Al Ajooz, and Allah knows best.  I could not find much more in regards to Al Yasa' (peace be upon Him) from Islamic sources.

As for him from the bible, it is says from it that he was a wonder maker of the northern kingdom of Isreal, [Source (for further reading)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elisha#Biblical_biography)

In the end, only Allah knows best.

Main Source of this answer: [Tafseer Atabari](http://qurancomplex.com/Quran/tafseer/Tafseer.asp?l=arb&t=tabary&nSora=6&nAya=86#6_86)

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the Answer of @مجاهد :

- In (tafsir) [at-tahrir wa-tanwir](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=61&surano=6&ayano=86) i found another name (My own translation, so be careful):
  اليسع: the hebrew original name is Elysha' and he was changed into al-Yas'a in Arabic.

He is the son of Shafit 
 شافاط from the people of Eel Maholah آبل محولة. He was a farmer before he became a Prophet taught by the Prophet Elias إلياس (May peace be upon him) (who according a narration of ibn 'Abbas (peace be upon both of them) was [his uncle](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A5%D9%8A%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A7)) during the reign of the king [Ahab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahab) and afterwards he followed the teaching of Elias and had apparently some miracles for Bani Israel in Ariyha أريحا and elsewhere. And he died during the reign of the king  يوءاش [Jehoash (?)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehoash_of_Israel) around 840 B.C. and he was buried in [Samara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaria).

> وهو ابن ( شافاط ) من أهل ( آبل محولة ) . كان فلاحا فاصطفاه الله للنبوءة على يد الرسول إلياس في مدة ( آخاب ) وصحب إلياس . ولما رفع إلياس لازم سيرة إلياس وظهرت له معجزات لبني إسرائيل في ( أريحا ) وغيرها . وتوفي في مدة الملك ( يوءاش ) ملك إسرائيل وكانت وفاته سنة أربعين وثمانمائة 840 قبل المسيح ودفن بالسامرة . والألف واللام في اليسع من أصل الكلمة ، ولكن الهمزة عوملت معاملة همزة الوصل للتخفيف  فأشبه الاسم الذي تدخل عليه اللام التي للمح الأصل مثل العباس ، وما هي منها .

he also added that the "ال" of the name are (the same as the) original (hebrew). This statement is a bit discuessed among scholars as al-Qushayru says that "ال" has been added as one can find in tafsir at-Tabari!

---

Differences in the Qiraat:

In the Quran Readings the majority read his name اليسع with a sukun on the "lam, ل" (this lam is silent), but among the Kufi's al-Kissa-i الكسائي and Hamza حمزة and Khalaf خلف read it الليسع al-layasa' with a shida on the 2nd (not silent but with a doubled consonant) "lam, ل". They used this pronunciation to make the name sound more like a non-Arabic name according to Imam at-Tabari!

---

- [Al-Qurtobi](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=48&surano=6&ayano=86) added to this: that Al-Yas'a was a companion of Elyas (so they are different as the Quran quotes each of them in the same Verse) and they both lived before Zakaria, Yahya and 'Issa (Peace be upon them). Soem pretended that Elias is Idriss but this isn't true as Idriss was a Grandfather of Noh and Elyas was an offspring of Noh. Some pretended that Elias or Al-Yasa' is/was al_Khidr...

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

His English name is [Elisha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elisha). He was one of the prophets of Israelites, his time was after that of "الیاس" [Elijah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elijah).

Comment: Wikipedia is hardly a definitive source for Islamic information. This answer doesn't really tell me much I don't already know from the two ayaat.

Comment: @ashes999, see the section about Islamic view at the end of the article. It has some references that you can check. In any case, he is a prophet of Judaism and the English name is Elisha. These are quite certain.

Comment: I actually read it before posting my comment. Sorry, I don't see this as a valuable answer. (If you see value in the Islamic View section, you should quote relevant parts in your answer.)

Comment: @ashes999, I think I have mentioned the most important information about who he is. I am not sure what you are looking for more than that, your question is not very specific. What do you want to know about him? (btw, if you had read the Wikipedia article before posting the question then you should fix your question. It doesn't say so right now.)